# Win10 Enterprise system keeps enabling screensaver

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, screensaver

I have a windows 10 enterprise system. The screen keeps timing out and displaying the lock screen after 20 minutes. I am both local and domain administrator. I've disabled the screensaver in the registry both in HKCU and HKU. Gpedit shows Enable Screen Saver is set to no. The screen saver options menu shows a screensaver of "none" and a timeout of 20 minutes, despite the fact that I've edited the registry to disable the timeout. The power settings are configured appropriately - the system is not sleeping, the screensaver is just activating for some reason.

Is there another key besides the ones in HKCU/Control Panel/Desktop and HKU/.DEFAULT/Control Panel/Desktop that I need to fiddle with to truly break the screensaver once and for all?

Comment: Does there exist a registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization` and in it a DWORD item named `NoLockScreen`? If not, create it with the value of `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the local group policy ought to do the trick:

1. Run `GPEDIT.MSC` locally
2. Navigate to *User Configuration* → *Administrative Templates* → *Control Panel* → *Personalization*
3. Set 'Enable Screen Saver' to 'Disabled'
4. Reboot

Comment: It does not. There seems to be a lingering setting somewhere.